# Show that a group action on the set of $1D$ subspaces is transitive

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions

Let $X = \{Span(v)\ |\ 0\neq v\in\mathbb{F}^n\}$, and let $G = SL_n$. Define an action
$$
A.Span(v) = Span(Av)
$$
I need to show that this action is transitive. Here is my attempt:

Let $v,w\in\mathbb{F}^n$. If $w = \lambda v$, then let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be a basis to $\mathbb{F}^n$ with $v_1=v$. We therefore, in this basis representation, define
$$
A_{ij} = \begin{cases}
\lambda & i = j = 1 \\
\frac{1}{\lambda} & i = j = 2 \\ 
1 & i = j\neq 1,2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, in this basis, $Av = w$, and therefore $A.Span(v) = Span(w)$, and $\det{A} = 1$.

If $v,w$ are linearly independent, then let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$ such that $v_1=v, v_2=w$. We define
$$
A_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & i =1, j = 2 \\
-1 & i=2, j=1 \\
1 & i = j\neq 2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, in this basis, $Av = w$, and therefore $A.Span(v) = Span(w)$ and $\det{A} =1$.

Is this OK?

Comment: I believe that $v=\lambda w$ case is not ok. This matrix do not send $v$ to $w$. But you can simply take $A$ as the identity matrix in $v=\lambda w$ case.

Comment: @Levent The matrix sends $v$ to $\lambda v = w$

Comment: Oh wait now I've noticed. It sends the coordinate vector of $v$ to coordinate vector of $w$. Yeah it works. But in the second case I guess you should take $v_2=-w$ not $w$.

Comment: You haven't dealt with the case $n=1$, but that case is easy.